# SwiftUI performing action after location lookup

Tags: swiftui

I have a lookup form which accepts a postcode or manually entered coordinates, and then does a lookup. Also a LocationButton which when clicked, does get the location, but I want to display the coordinates in the TextField and then do the lookup.

When the location is available, it can display in a new TextField but I cannot get it to display in the existing Textfield by updating the bound variable.

When I try to update the bound place variable, I receive the error : Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'

The same error occurs if trying to print the results

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation
import CoreLocationUI

class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    let manager = CLLocationManager()

    @Published var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D?

    override init() {
        super.init()
        manager.delegate = self
    }

    func requestLocation() {
        manager.requestLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        location = locations.first?.coordinate
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
         print("error:: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

}

struct LocationView: View {
    @StateObject var locationManager = LocationManager()
    @State var place = "SW1A 0AA"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Form {
                VStack {
                    Text("Where")
                    TextField("Location", text: $place)
                    HStack {
                        Button("Lookup") {
                            print("Lookup \(place)")
                        }
                        
                        LocationButton {
                            locationManager.requestLocation()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            if let location = locationManager.location {
              //  These lines are what I want to do, but cause this error : Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'
              //  $place = "\(location.latitude), \(location.longitude)"
              //  print('Look up \(location.latitude), \(location.longitude)')
                Text("Your location: \(location.latitude), \(location.longitude)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could convert your `LocationManager.requestLocation()` to be an async function, e.g.

```
class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    private let manager = CLLocationManager()
    private var completion: ((Result<CLLocationCoordinate2D?, Error>) -> Void)?
        
    override init() {
        super.init()
        manager.delegate = self
    }
    
    func requestLocation() async throws -> CLLocationCoordinate2D? {
        try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
            requestLocation { result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let coordinate):
                    continuation.resume(returning: coordinate)
                case .failure(let error):
                    continuation.resume(throwing: error)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func requestLocation(completion: @escaping (Result<CLLocationCoordinate2D?, Error>) -> Void) {
        self.completion = completion
        manager.requestLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        completion?(.success(locations.first?.coordinate))
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        completion?(.failure(error))
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
LocationButton {
    Task {
        if let location = try await locationManager.requestLocation() {
            place = "\(location.latitude), \(location.longitude)"
        }
    }
}
```